# Ignoring lines in a file TCL

Tags: tcl

Suppose I have a file1 with a few queries inside,

```
Query 1
Query 2
Query 3
```

And I have a normal text file2 containing a bunch of data

```
Data 1 Query 1 something something
Data something Query 2 something something
Something Query 3 something something
Data1 continue no query
Data2 continue no query
```

How do I create a loop such that it ignores the lines containing queries from file1 and prints only lines without the queries in the file? so in this case only these values gets printed

```
Data1 continue no query
Data2 continue no query
```

i tried producing the results using this loop script i made

**Storing the queries to be ignored from file1 into $wlistItems**

```
set openFile1 [open file1.txt r]
while {[gets openFile1 data] > -1} {
set wlist $data
append wlistItems "{$wlist}\n"
}
close $openFile1
```

**Processing file2 to print lines without ignored queries**

```
set openFile2 [open file2.txt r]
while {[gets $openFile2 data] > -1} {
for {set n 0} {$n < [llength $wListItems]} {incr n} {
if {[regexp -all "[lindex $wListItems $n]" $data all value]} {
continue
}
puts $data
}
}
close $openFile2
```

However, the script does not skip the lines. It instead prints out repeated data from file2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while {[gets $openFile2 data] > -1} {
    set found 0
    for {set n 0} {$n < [llength $wListItems]} {incr n} {
        if {[regexp -all "[lindex $wListItems $n]" $data all value]} {
            set found 1
            break
        }
    }
    if {!$found} {
        puts $data
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh, your solution works perfectly. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

```
package require fileutil

set queries [join [split [string trim [::fileutil::cat file1]] \n] |]
::fileutil::foreachLine line file2 {
    if {![regexp ($queries) $line]} {
        puts $line
    }
}
```

The first command (after the `package require`) reads the file with the queries and packs them up as a set of branches (`Query 1|Query 2|Query 3`). The second command processes the second file line by line and prints those lines that don't contain any of those branches.

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do this:

```
puts [exec grep -Fvf file1 file2]
```